# How to restrict access in Api's based on Roles with Jhipster

Tags: java, spring, jhipster

I am working on a jhipster project.If i have three roles say A,B and C and i want to limit access of an particular API to only A & B.How can i manage the security of Api in such a way that other user roles wont able to access it?

Comment: I have not used jhipster, but do you have a  spring security.xml for your application ?

Comment: @FreakyThommi: no

Comment: It can also be a java configuration. Search for  ".authorizeRequests() "in your java files. If you are not finding this too, you havent enabled security for your project yet. If you are not using spring security, you will have to enable spring security first. You can start at this link https://jhipster.github.io/security/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on which type of JHipster application you are using, the file you need is called `WebSecurityConfiguration` (for monoliths) or `MicroserviceSecurityConfiguration` (for microservice appplications).

There, in the `configure` method you will find the default line

```
.antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
```

which means, you only need to be authenticated to get access to any url behind the /api prefix.

To apply some custom role based rule, you add some

```
.antMatchers("/api/my-url/").hasRole("A")
```

**before the mentioned line**, or similar methods, as hasAnyRole, hasAuthority, or access(), for more complex statements

As an alternative, you may use the `@Secured` or `@PreAuthorize` annotations on concrete methods, to have more fine grained access control

Answer (score 2):

In Jhipster genereated project,To restrict any URI path to be used only by admin,you need to add it in the configure method of SecurityConfiguration.java class.
You need to add

> .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)

mentioning the URI inside the .antMatchers.
So that it will not be availble for the users with the Role "ROLE_USER".

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .addFilterBefore(corsFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint())
    .and()
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        .headers()
        .frameOptions()
        .disable()
    .and()
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/register").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/activate").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/authenticate").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/account/reset_password/init").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/account/reset_password/finish").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/profile-info").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/swagger-resources/configuration/ui").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/index.html").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
    .and()
        .apply(securityConfigurerAdapter());

}
```

Or If you want to restrict only a few particular API's,you can just add the annotation

> @Secured({ AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN })

in top of the API which you want to restrict.

You can do this restriction for any roles and together also by separating it with a comma.

> @Secured({ AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN, AuthoritiesConstants.SELLER })